# Minimize buttons are disabled when I connect an external monitor

Tags: macos, display

Whenever I connect an external monitor all the minimize buttons on existing apps get disabled (they are gray).  Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not expected behaviour, and without more information sounds like you might have a 3rd-part window management tool running that could affect the behaviour of existing windows.

If you run applications in Full-Screen mode, the "Minimise" button does get greyed out, if that helps

Comment: They aren't fullscreen. I also don't have a third party window manager. It feels mostly like a defect, since it only happens when I connect the external monitor.